# static_assert before a constructor's initialiser list

Tags: c++, static-assert

There is a non-templated class which has a templated constructor. Is it possible to check a static assertion before initialising member variables in such constructor?

For example, the following code executes `T::value()` before checking that `T` has such method.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    MyClass(const T &t)
        : m_value(t.value())
    {
        static_assert(HasValueMethod<T>::value, "T must have a value() method");
    }

private:
    int m_value;
};
```

Placing `static_assert` in a constructor's body works fine except it prints "T must have a value() method" at the very end, after all error messages from the member initialiser list, e.g.:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘MyClass::MyClass(const T&) [with T = int]’:
prog.cpp:24:16:   required from here
prog.cpp:12:21: error: request for member ‘value’ in ‘t’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
         : m_value(t.value())
                   ~~^~~~~
prog.cpp:14:9: error: static assertion failed: T must have a value() method
         static_assert(HasValueMethod<T>::value, "T must have a value() method");
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I find this a bit confusing and wonder if it would be possible to print "T must have a value() method" before trying to initialise member variables.

I know that I could use `enable_if` and SFINAE to disable this constructor for inappropriate `T`s, but I would like to tell a user something more meaningful than "method not found".

Comment: Initialize the member variable after the assert in the constructor body?

Comment: @tambre, this would work, but I would like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: @tambre: You cannot initialise a member variable after the body execution has begun.

Comment: How about a small inline utility member function template? Put that static assert there. Then write `m_value(util_get_value(t))`. Trust NRVO to do the right thing and voila.

Comment: Well I guess you could do enable_if to do a proper constructor, and have a fallback constructor which just assert the message you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `std::enable_if` to SFINAE out the constructor that does the `static_assert` based on whether `T` has the function member `value()`, keeping the real implementation separated.

The first constructor is selected if `T` has the `value()` method, and is implemented as normally (except that it needs the `std::enable_if` in order to be selected):

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<HasValueMethod<T>::value>>
MyClass(const T &t) : m_value(t.value())
{}
```

So we need the second constructor to be SFINAEd out of function overloading, since the first one already knows that `T::value` exists:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!HasValueMethod<T>::value>>
MyClass(const T &, ...)
{
  static_assert(HasValueMethod<T>::value, "T must have a value() method");
}
```

Note the variadic parameter `...`: it is needed in order to differentiate the constructor's prototype, so it doesn't collide with the first one (they need to be different, otherwise ambiguous prototypes result in compile error). You won't pass anything to it, it's just there to make it a different prototype.

Note as well that the predicate for `std::enable_if` is the same but negated. When `HasValueMethod<T>::value` is false, the first constructor is SFINAEd out of function overloading, but not the second one, which then would trigger the static assert.

You still need to use `HasValueMethod<T>::value` in the static assert's parameter, so it depends on `T` to be executed. Otherwise, putting just `false` there would make it always trigger regardless of being selected out.

Here's what GCC prints when `T` has no `.value()`:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'MyClass::MyClass(const T&, ...) [with T = A; <template-parameter-1-2> = void]':
main.cpp:35:18:   required from here
main.cpp:21:9: error: static assertion failed: T must have a value() method
         static_assert(HasValueMethod<T>::value, "T must have a value() method");

         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here's Clang's:

```
main.cpp:21:9: error: static_assert failed "T must have a value() method"
        static_assert(HasValueMethod<T>::value, "T must have a value() method");
        ^
```

All in all, there's an issue (as pointed out by @T.C. in comments) with this approach: `MyClass` is now convertible from anything from the point of view of unevaluated contexts. That is,

```
static_assert(std::is_convertible_v</*anything*/, MyClass>); // Always true.
```

In C++20, when hopefully concepts are in, this is easily solved with a `requires` clause:

```
template <typename T>
  requires HasValueMethod<T>::value
MyClass(const T &t) : m_value(t.value())
{}
```

You could directly express `HasValueMethod<T>` in the `requires` clause just as well:

```
template <typename T>
  requires requires (T a) { { a.value() } -> int; }
MyClass(const T &t) : m_value(t.value())
{}
```

Or transforming `HasValueMethod<T>` into a real concept:

```
template <typename T>
concept HasValueMethod = requires (T a) {
    { a.value() } -> int;
};

// Inside `class MyClass`.
template <typename T>
  requires HasValueMethod<T>
MyClass(const T &t) : m_value(t.value())
{}
```

Such solutions make `std::is_convertible_v<T, MyClass>` work as expected as well.

Comment: I would say a template that was SFINAEd out will not be considered during overload resolution. Also a static_assert in a template hast no effect as long as the template is not instantiated. Therefore there is no need for an additional parameter in the constructor and static_assert(false) should also work.

Comment: It's considered during overload resolution until something SFINAE it out.

Comment: Your `MyClass` is now convertible from everything under the sun.

Comment: @T.C.: It already was, the custom assertion for illegal conversions requires it.  Definitely unfortunate when testing for convertibility.

Answer (score 4):

if you don't plan to SFINAE-constrain the constructor and you *always* want an error to be raised when `HasValueMethod` is false, you could just write an 'hard' variant of your trait class:

```
template<class T>
struct AssertValueMethod
{
  static_assert(HasValueMethod<T>::value, "T must have a value() method");
  using type = void; // note: needed to ensure instantiation, see below ...
};

template< typename T, typename = typename AssertValueMethod<T>::type >
MyClass(const T &t): ...
```

moreover, if, later on, you want to add a sfinae selected overload, you can always write a proper delegating constructor without changing the static assertion logic ...

Comment: why the down-vote? am I missing something? please explain

Comment: I am not a down-voter and this approach seems to solve the issue, but IMO it is a bit over-engineered. Why do you need to inherit from `std::true_type`? Why do you need a template alias?

Comment: @Kane you must instantiate AssertValueMethodImpl in order for the static_assert to fire; in this case, the implicit instantiation is obtained via its member 'type', I choosed the one in true_type just for brevity. The alias is there just for convenience. I'll edit to clarify ...

Comment: It seems that this one works as well: `template<typename T> class AssertValueMethod { static_assert(...); };` and `template<typename T, typename = AssertValueMethod<T>> MyClass(...) { ... }`. Or have I missed anything?

Comment: @Kane, it depends on the '...', but that looks like a compiler bug. By itself, the mere appereance of AssertValueMethod<whatever> should not imply its implicit instantiation, for example see [this](https://godbolt.org/g/9YDh8P).

Comment: @Kane, more specifically, see [temp.inst](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.inst), the first and successive paragraphs for more details

Answer (score 4):

Bring the `static_assert()` closer to the usage.  In this case, a helper function will do it:

```
class MyClass
{
    template<typename T>
    static int get_value(const T& t)
    {
        static_assert(HasValueMethod<T>::value, "T must have a value() method");
        return t.value();
    }

public:
    template<typename T>
    MyClass(const T &t)
        : m_value(get_value(t))
    {
    }

private:
    int m_value;
};
```

Not only does this fix the order of the error messages, but it lets you reuse the message for every path that needs the `value()` member function.

Comment: Now that I'm reading the question comments (which weren't available in review queue) I see StoryTeller already suggested this approach.